# C# Pubnub SDK usage pattern

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pubnub

I am using [C# Pubnub SDK](https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp). To interact with Pubnub I use `Pubnub` class. So what are the best practices of managing `Pubnub` object? I assume it is quite heavy. I don't want to create new object whenever I need to do something with Pubnub.

I have a Web application. Can I simply put Pubnub object into a static field and make it available from everywhere in the application? Are there any potential problems with it?

Currently I am using only `HereNow` pubnub function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrei, you can re-use the object as needed for multiple calls. When you are done with it, to free memory, you can clean it up via the

```
EndPendingRequests()
```

method. More info on that here: https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp/tree/master/csharp.net#object-cleanup

Comment: @andrei our lead engineers will be commenting as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Geremy. Is it ok if I just let this object live for a whole application lifetime? Are there any potential problems with it?

Comment: There are no known issues with that Andrei.